# Simple JS innerHTML question - Include image src held in var

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a var named src, how can I write that into innerHTML?

E.g.

```
var src = $(this).attr("src");
_html.innerHTML = '<img src="" />';
```

Place the var src as the img src?

Comment: Why not: 
var src = this.src;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
var src = $(this).attr("src");
_html.innerHTML = '<img src="' + src + '" />';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
_html.innerHTML = '<img src="' + src + '" />';
```

Comment: Someone actually rated this down?!

Comment: That's bizarre - here's a +1 :)

Comment: Haha, thank you, just shocked more than anything as I was the first to answer!

Comment: I know - SO can be a crazy, crazy world sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using jQuery. If so, you can do it this way:

```
var src = $(this).attr("src");
var $img = $("<img>").attr("src",src)
$("#yourObject").append($img)
```

Comment: The equivalent would actually be `$("#yourObject").html($img)`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
_html.innerHTML = '<img src="'+src+'" />';
```